# Any alternative to CNAME records for the root domain?

Tags: google, domains, dns, cname, parking

I have couple domain names which I wanted to park the domain with [Bodis](https://www.bodis.com). But I also need their subdomain to be available for me for email access (i.e. mail.example.com). The domain is registered via Google Domains. Bodis give two options to do so. The first is to use their nameservers

```
NS1.BODIS.COM
NS2.BODIS.COM
```

The second is to use CNAME records:

```
www 61076.BODIS.COM
(blank) 61076.BODIS.COM
* 61076.BODIS.COM
```

However, Google Domains does not allow the (blank) CNAME as it throws the following error:

```
CNAME records for the root domain are not supported
```

I am not sure if it will enough to have the `www` and `*` CNAME records, or not? But, is there any alternative to have both the cream and the pie?

Answer (score 2):

The Bodis support team returned to me with the following:

> If you require that your email.example.com subdomain is available to
>   you, you're going to need to omit * (asterisks) part of your zone file
>   and only include www 61076.BODIS.COM
>
> When CNAME forwarding, typically only the third level subdomain
>   (www.example.com) can be forwarded while the parent domain
>   (example.com) resolves to the registrar.
>
> Therefore, you will need to use A record forwarding if you intend to
>   park the second level parent domain (example.com). Please forward
>   example.com to either www.example.com or our parking server IP:
>   199.59.243.120, using your A record.